# data not binding to select list in knockout

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using a simple select list like this in cshtml

```
<select data-bind="options: model.availableCountries"></select>
```

and the following data is assigned to options in the script.

```
model.availableCountries = ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']);
```

But it doesn't bind any value. The model is having this value when debugged. I also tried

```
<select data-bind="options: model.contacts,
  value: model.selectContactName,
  optionsText: 'Name',
  optionsCaption: 'Select name'">
</select>
```

This does not even show the caption. Is there anything i am missing?

Comment: Please show the line of code that declares `model` and assigns a value.

Comment: model.availableCountries = ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']);

Comment: I asked about `model`, not about `model.whatever`. I suspect you have a line similar to `var model = this;` in your viewmodel.

Comment: var model = ko.mapping.fromJS(data); this availableCountries  is not in this data.I am newly adding this after that

Comment: You have that line somewhere? `ko.applyBindings(model);` Without that, Knockout won't do anything for you.

Comment: no this is not there,let me try to add this.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A basic example based on your question.

```js
const viewModel = {
    availableCountries: ko.observableArray(['France', 'Germany', 'Spain']),
    countryPlaceholder: 'Where do you live?',
    selectedCountry: ko.observable(),
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
  value: selectedCountry,
  optionsCaption: countryPlaceholder">
</select>

<p data-bind="visible: selectedCountry">
    You selected: <span data-bind="text: selectedCountry"></span>
</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```